# Begin transaction with 2 DBContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, dbcontext, rollback

The idea : I am trying to run an insertion to 2 databases using 2 different dbContext, the goal is to allow a role back on the insertion from both QBs in case of an exception from ether one of the insertions.

My code:

```
using (var db1 = new DbContext1())
{
    db1.Database.Connection.Open();
    using (var trans = db1.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //do the insertion into db1
        db1.SaveChanges();

        using (var db2 = new DbContext2())
        {
            //do the insertions into db2
            db2.SaveChanges();
        }
        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```

On the first call to save changes: db1.SaveChanges(); I get an invalid operation exception : sqlconnection does not support parallel transactions

I tried figuring out what does it exactly mean, why does it happen and how to solve it but haven't been able to achieve that.

So my questions are:
What does it exactly mean? and why do I get this exception?
How can I solve it?
Is there a way to use the begin transaction is a different way that won't cause this error?

Also, is this the proper way to use begin transaction or should I do something different?

***For clarification, I am using the db1.Database.Connection.Open(); because otherwise I get an "connection is close" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I was simply abusing the syntax, so to help anyone who may stumble upon this question this is the proper way to do this:

```
using (var db1 = new DbContext1())
{
    using (var trans = db1.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //do the insertion into db1
            db1.SaveChanges();

            using (var db2 = new DbContext2())
            {
                //do the insertions into db2
                db2.SaveChanges();
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            trans.Rollback();  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to strech your connection and transaction across two `DbContext`, you may go for handling your connection and transaction outside of your `DbContext`, something like this :

```
using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dbc1 = new System.Data.Entity.DbContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false))
            {
                dbc1.Database.UseTransaction(trans);
                // do some work
                // ...
                dbc1.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var dbc2 = new System.Data.Entity.DbContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false))
            {
                dbc2.Database.UseTransaction(trans);
                // do some work
                // ...
                dbc2.SaveChanges();
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            trans.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this work in a case that my 2 dbContexts dont have the same connection string? On first look it seems like it won't....

Comment: @petric no it won't work with two databases, and I guess your solution won't work either ( as I guess `trans.Rollback()`will not rollback changes made in db2 in any combination of connection strings) 
To work across several databases, you should have a look at TransactionScopes :
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/entityframework/1170/transaction-scope-databases-adonet-entity-framework-aspnet-mvc

Comment: TransactionScopes requiers that I will change the sequrity settings on the client side which is not an option. You can look at the answer I posted witch works great.

Comment: @petric your solution will work as long as `trans.Commit()` or any code running after db2.SaveChanges() does not throw an Exception. db2 changes would not be rolled back in this case....

Comment: A. If both save changes worked I don't need a rollback cause my goal was achieved. B.If the exception was thrown inside the try catch scope that is inside the begin transaction scope they will be rolled back.